# How to wrap a package

Tags: oracle

I have created a package which body contains more than 7000 lines, I want to wrap it using DBMS_DLL SUBPROGRAMS.  Can anyone please suggest me the steps?

Comment: +1, can I ask why you're not breaking the package down into multiple packages instead though?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "7000 lines" translates to more than 32k you can do something like

```
declare
  l_sql dbms_sql.varchar2a;
begin
  l_sql(1) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_foo ';
  l_sql(2) := 'AS ';
  l_sql(3) := '  PROCEDURE proc_foo( col1 IN NUMBER ); ';
  l_sql(4) := 'END;';
  dbms_ddl.create_wrapped( l_sql, 1, 4 );
end;
```

Make sure that you have the actual source of your package stored safely outside the database-- there is no way to unwrap the package once it is wrapped so any future modifications will need to start with the unwrapped source.

Comment: Hi Justin,                                                         Thank you for your reply.Do I have to mention l_sql(1) ..... l_sql(7000) and ' '  ?

Comment: @Gurujothi.D - If you want to use the `DBMS_DDL` package and your DDL statement is more than 32k, you would have to construct an associative array of type `dbms_sql.varchar2a` with the individual components of your DDL.  You could choose to generate fewer elements in the array that are longer or to create more elements in the array that are shorter as I did.  I find one element per line of code (so 7000 elements in your case) the most readable and the easiest to generate from a text editor where the DDL statement exists.